# remove the edges that are appearing around the images on Microsoft Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, vml

I'm trying to remove the edges that are appearing around the images I'm putting in an html. The images are a hyperlink and when clicked open an email to be answered.

It only happens on the outlook client, and my client has 95% of his employees using the outlook client.

[image]

```
<div>
    <!--[if mso]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="mailto:#$18087$#?subject=Pesquisa de Satisfação - Excelente #RequestNumber#&amp;body=#NÃO MODIFIQUE ESTA LINHA E NEM O ASSUNTO DO EMAIL 10#%0AExcelente! Diga-nos o que você mais gostou:" style="height:80px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:80px;">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center>
            <![endif]-->
            <a href="mailto:#$18087$#?subject=Pesquisa de Satisfação - Excelente #RequestNumber#&amp;body=#NÃO MODIFIQUE ESTA LINHA E NEM O ASSUNTO DO EMAIL 10#%0AExcelente! Diga-nos o que você mais gostou:"
                style="color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:40px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;"><img src="http://www.grupomoura.com/sistemas-moura/smiling.png" width="40" height="40"></a>
            <!--[if mso]>
        </center>
    </v:rect>
    <![endif]-->
</div>
```

Comment: `<v:rect>` and related are part of VML. While you can use them in HTML in specific situations (older Office products mainly), they're not themselves HTML and are [obsolete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language). Thanks Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this may be due to `v:rect`. According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/vml/msdn-online-vml-strokeweight-attribute) the `v:rect` has the following trait:

> The value is duplicated from the Weight attribute of the Stroke element. If a number is specified, but no units are added, the default unit of measurement is the Emu. If no value is specified, the default is 1 pixel (1px).

This should be solvable by adding `strokeweight="0"` to the `v:rect` element.

*Note: This is a best guess answer as I don't have access to Outlook to test.*